# Disable Android keyboard keys programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I am trying to enable few keys from being pressed on my custom keyboard before requirements are met and disable them when they are not met.

I am also trying to create a key which can be pressed and act as a sticky button but behind the code, only the key image is changed (sticky is disabled in xml) as I am unable to find a solution for detecting sticky keys using Xamarin.

Keyboard XML: 
( i have removed android:isSticky="true" from code, this is just part of the code that needs to be disabled and enabled, bottom part of the codes that are not posted just consist of numbers)

```
<Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="1000"
            android:keyLabel="A"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="1001"
            android:keyLabel="B"
            android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="1002"
            android:keyLabel="C"
            android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="1003"
            android:keyLabel="D"
            android:isModifier="true"
            android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="1004"
            android:keyLabel="E"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    </Row>
```

Activity Keyboard Init Part:

```
mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this,Resource.Layout.Keyboard);
mKeyboardView = this.FindViewById<KeyboardView> (Resource.Id.keyboardview);
mKeyboardView.Keyboard = mKeyboard;
mKeyboardView.PreviewEnabled = false;
var keyboardListener = new MyKeyboardListener(this);
mKeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener = keyboardListener;
```

I already have the keyboardListener working and was able to detect OnKey, but the problem here is how do I modify each individual key? How do I detect each individual key on my mKeyboardView and edit its value (disabling them or even changing their background image onclick)?

Comment: you can identify like KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A this

Comment: Can you elaborate further? I'm trying to modify code = '1000' and disable it when the edittext has more than 5 digits. If 5 digit is met, i would like to change the background of this Key. How can I do that?